# How to fit small dowel/barrel nut into a large hole?

Tags: dowel

Please see this image from an old desk I have inherited:

[image]

I have concluded that these holes need dowel/barrel nuts and then at-most an M8 bolt that shall be screwed into them. It is also possible to use M6. The height of the dowel nut must be 14mm. I do not have the parts that are required to assemble this and am trying to figure out what I need to buy.

The hole has diameter of 15mm. I am unable to find dowel/barrel nut that has this diameter. All the ones I can find are 10mm - 12mm. Now the question is what to do.

One idea I have come up with is, buy wooden dowel stick with 15mm diameter. Cut it and put it into the holes. Use wood glue and then sand the surface. Now, drill a small hole that exactly fits the smaller 10mm metal dowel/barrel nuts and another hole for the bolt.

Since these holes are on the side of the desk, I do not see any reason why a cam-lock would be fit into here. Thus, I have ruled out the cam lock.

Comment: These are the uprights of the desk, yes? If so, you are probably mistaken about the cam lock being inappropriate. Maybe show us a picture of the underside of the top.

Comment: that part goes on the right side of the desk. It faces right rather than up.

Comment: Maybe show us the other parts in context. Whether the other part is a modesty panel or a solid back, I suspect you’ll find 5mm holes where the 15mm side holes line up.

Comment: A 12mm barrel nut will fit into a 15mm hole. Once the bolt is threaded into the nut's threads and tightened, it won't go anywhere. (Unless, of course, I'm totally misunderstanding what you're asking.) Yeah, some more pics for more context would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> Since these holes are on the side of the desk, I do not see any reason why a cam-lock would be fit into here. Thus, I have ruled out the cam lock.

I suspect that you're incorrect. A typical [cam nut](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DLWC7RP) is 15 mm in diameter, and the small intersecting hole from the edge appears to be sized perfectly for the [mating screw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K1KYW4L).

Is it possible that you've mistaken the inside of the panel for the outside?